# Multi-select rows on a DataGrid

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to select the entire rows of a DataGrid (gridActivePlayers) for each occurrence of a single customer appears on the grid. Here is my method. I'm having problems with the 'For Each' loop:

```
    Private Sub CustomerBindingSource_PositionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  Handles CustomerBindingSource.PositionChanged
    Dim drvCustomer As DataRowView = CType(Me.CustomerBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)
    Dim selCustomer As Integer = drvCustomer.Item("CustomerID")

    ActivePlayersBindingSource.Position = Me.ActivePlayersBindingSource.Find("CustomerID", selCustomer)
' Here is what I need to implement
    For Each
        MsgBox(1)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a winforms or asp.net application?

Comment: datagridview.selectall() ..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx):

> To programmatically select a row, set its Selected property to true.

See [DataGridViewRow.Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.selected.aspx) for more info.